# Select or input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In my app I have a form for creating new trip. Model Trip has field finish_address. For setup the finish_address in I use select in simple form to select address from user's addressbook. But I want to make a better form: if there isn't necessary address, user can add it using input field.

So I need to make form with to types of setup finish_address. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 basic options.

You can use autocomplete on a text input, populating a dynamic crop-down with know values. 
There are several gems available to get you started in this direction, like https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.

Alternatively, you can add an "other" option to a select input, populated with your known values. When the "other" item is selected, display a previously hidden text input with the same name below the select input. The "lowest" element will take precedence, for what gets sent to the controller.

In the controller, just do a [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by), using your provided value.

These options both require javascript, but you can eliminate the need for javascript if you make your select a non-db-backed attribute, and manipulate your params accordingly, as they come in to the model. This might help with validations, as well.